# Guard against null in spring expression

Tags: jsp, spring-el

I have the following in a jsp page, where bar is a field (which can be null) of foo

```
<c:set var="fieldAccessorsSuppliedToComponent" value="foo.bar.name" />

//omissions

<spring:eval expression="${fieldAccessorsSuppliedToComponent}" var="currentField"/>
```

I have no control over what `fieldAccessorsSuppliedToComponent` is going to be, `foo.bar1.bar2.bar3.address.city` is possible and any step could be null. I have currently solved it by looping over 'fields' ->

```
<c:set var="fields" value="${fn:split(column, '.')}" />
```

and testing each step for null. Its a mess. Can it be done with something inbuilt in SPeL

What is the simplest way to make it work with nulls? Silently failing and not setting currentField is ideal.

Comment: Did you try *null-safe navigator*: `value="foo.bar?.name"`. See here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-operator-safe-navigation

Comment: Awesome, I'd given it a tick if it'd been an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where bar is a field (which can be null) of foo

The *Null-safer Navigator* operator comes to the rescue:

```
value="foo.bar?.name"
```

See more info in the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-operator-safe-navigation